# How to fix error with Reactjs with making link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

[image]

Hi! I try do to links in react and all time i got that errors as on screen minimum 8 sometimes i got 32 and I don't know how to fix

App.jsx

```
import { Layout } from "./Components/Layout";

import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Layout.jsx

```
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <header>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/posts">Blog</Link>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </header>
    </>

  )
}

export {Layout}
```

This code I making using tutorials from Youtube and official documentations but it don't work.

Please help. Thank

Answer (score 2):

Routes need to be inside a  tag or within a router created using createBrowserRouter.

Answer (score 1):

In index.JS import BrowserRouter and replace React.StrictMode with it. Strict mode can cause things to render multiple times so I usually get rid of it.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from “react-router-dom”;


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: No, still have same error

Comment: @AeroxerSupport are you running react router version 5 or 6?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: I got react 18.2.0

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: react routes 6 version

Comment: Try taking the { Link } import out of App and put <Layout /> above <Routes> in the return statement

Comment: No, still have erro

Answer (score 0):

The Routes should have been wrapped by `BrowserRouter` component. It should look like this:

```
import { Layout } from "./Components/Layout";

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
return (
      <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Can you show me where? Plese)

Comment: The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42724:7
App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. - now I got this)

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use all routing related actions under router context. You can achieve this by using `BrowserRouter` component as an HOC for `<App />`. 
 You can find more here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router

Comment: `The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42724:7

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.` - now I got this error

Comment: Send me the error. This message says their is an error but what error?

Comment: All errors in image in my question - error all time same